# Thorlabs PC4QM With TI DRV2700EVM

Tags: texas-instruments, piezo

I am working with a 650nF Thorlabs PC4QM piezo load, whose information I leave attached. And to carry out the operation I'm considering a Texas Instruments DRV2700EVM, has anyone had experience combining these two devices, or do you have any recommendations for use that you can provide me? From what I analyzed of the datasheets, there shouldn't be any problems, but any confirmation is welcome.

[image]